# Render menu in custom form-api module

Tags: 7, forms, routes

I've created a custom menu from the drupal admin panel, and have a custom module that uses drupal's form API. I'd like to render the custom menu in this module. Since this is using form API, I don't think it makes sense to use a template file, but I can't find any way to render a menu from the .module file itself. Not only would I like to render it, but I'd like to have control over which page region it's rendered in...How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got you right,but if you want to call a form on a menu item.Here is view for that
Implement

> [hook_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) - to build custom page page callback - return your custom
>   form here

Some sample code

```
function mymodulename_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['custom-menu'] = array(
    'title' => 'Your Custom Form',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('mymodulename_custom_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );
  return $items;
}

function mymodulename_custom_form() {
  $form = array();
  // your custom form code goes here
  return $form;
}
```